# How do I pass an arraylist into a different class

Tags: java, string, class, arraylist

Here is the code I'm using

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Message{

    Scanner input;
    String emailLine = "";
    String line;
    ArrayList<String> email = new ArrayList<String>();
    String emailString;
    String sender;
    String subject;
    String emailMIN;
    String[] newString;
    StringBuilder emailStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    public Message(String m)throws IOException{


    File inFile = new File ("mail.txt");
    input = new Scanner (inFile);
    String message;
    getEmails();
    }

    public void getEmails(){

    while(input.hasNextLine()){
            line = input.nextLine(); 
            System.out.println("Test, line: " + line);

                    if(line.equals("<END>")){
                    System.out.println("Test, <END> reached");
                    System.out.println("Test, email String: " +
emailStringBuilder.toString());
                            email.add(emailStringBuilder.toString());
                    }
                    else{
                            emailStringBuilder.append("\n" + line);
                    }
            }
            }
```

I'm trying to pass the email ArrayList into a different class so that I can break up the Strings of the ArrayList into separate Arrays. How do I do this? Also once I get it into a different class, how do I access each element of the ArrayList and break each element up into another ArrayList with each element separated by the lines?

Comment: The other class should have a a constructor that accepts an `ArrayList` -or- instantiate `Message` in the other class

Comment: The same way you'd pass any other object.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all an `ArrayList` is not a `List` of arrays. It's simply a `List` of items, in your case `String`.

If you want to pass an `ArrayList` to a different class you could simply do something like this:

```
public class MyOtherClass {

public void doSomething(ArrayList<String> myList) {
    // do something with "myList"
}
```

And then in your `Message` class:

```
MyOtherClass myClass = new MyOtherClass();
myClass.doSomething(email);
```

Is this helping?

**NOTE**

From your editing of the question I think you don't fully understand how `ArrayList` works. It is **not** a `List` of `Array`! It is simply an array implementation of the `List` interface for better performance in certain tasks. For more information read [the javadocs about ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

**EDIT**

As peeskillet was suggesting, you could also instantiate a `Message` class object in your new class and get the `ArrayList` from there, but then `email` would have to be a public field in your class `Message` or declare a getter method for `email`.

**EDIT**

Since you added more questions:

You can go through all the elements of an `ArrayList` like this:

```
For (String nextString : email) {
    System.out.println(nextString); // Or do whatever you want with it :)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `message.getEmails()` to get your emails.

Below is a sample code

```
public class Message{
Scanner input;
String emailLine = "";
String line;
List<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();
String emailString;
String sender;
String subject;
String emailMIN;
String[] newString;
StringBuilder emailStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

public Message(String m)throws IOException{


    File inFile = new File ("mail.txt");
    input = new Scanner (inFile);
    String message;
    populateEmails();
}

public void populateEmails(){

    while(input.hasNextLine()){
        line = input.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("Test, line: " + line);

        if(line.equals("<END>")){
            System.out.println("Test, <END> reached");
            System.out.println("Test, email String: " +
                    emailStringBuilder.toString());
            emails.add(emailStringBuilder.toString());
        }
        else{
            emailStringBuilder.append("\n" + line);
        }
    }

}

public List<String> getEmails() {
    return emails;
}
}
```